# performance (compilation, build, load, memory load) in the Java EE developement

Tags: php, performance, jakarta-ee, build

I would like to ask a question that bothers me all the time

in the developements with php: the debug and build of project are just a ctrl + s -> F5

but in the case of Java EE projects (especially when I use java frameworks like  jsf spring .... ) the simple change on the managed-beans (if JSF) or simply a java bean class .. I have to wait for the loading of the context .....

it takes me a long time despite the fact that the PC is powerful enough
and it creates occasional memory overload

=> Which reduces very significantly the productivity and demotivating

(I do not think most developers are resistant to it)

there is no solution to this problem?

thank you

Comment: Which app server do you use for Java development? Jetty is significantly faster in the "change file/reload page" cycle than most of the others I've tried...

Comment: I just test it but I do not happen to build my project with it (is it possible to show me how to use it for an existing maven eclipse project)

Answer (score 1):

**PHP**

You save a file. PHP is started with the file as a source, it interprets the contents, build op codes, executes, you get results. PHP stops.

**Java EE**

You save a file. You compile the project (a change in one file might change other class files). You also start an Application Server (expensive) or do a context reload (less expensive). It is like doing a Apache restart after every PHP file change. You leave the Application Server running, so subsequent requests will be fast.

But why all this trouble? Java requires an application reload because it doesn't interpret every class file on every request (like PHP does) so when changes happen a reload is required to the whole application. Another reason is that the JVM is a highly optimised beast and to have excellent performance you cannot have quick turnaround (the optimisations take time by nature). Think of running PHP with OP cache enabled and warmed up for each PHP file change.

For small applications the reload in Java EE is quite inexpensive but it gets worse once the application grows. Once you are using couple of frameworks then on application context reload will also trigger the initialisation of these frameworks.

If you want PHP like development experience then there is a commercial tool, [JRebel](http://jrebel.com) available. This tool will reload the new bytecode from the changed class files instead of doing a context reload.

Comment: thank you for your explanation, this tool allow to reload Java EE like php (only with cltr+s and no waiting) ????

Comment: there is not a free tools ?

Comment: No free tools that would give this kind of experience in Java EE. A combination of a lightweight servlet container, low footprint frameworks, a small project, SSD and powerful computer is a good start for a quick turnaround in Java.